# Asking a duplicate question for a different version of a tool

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print), which was asked presumably in the context of Python 2 (judging from the date).

I noticed that one of the answers with no votes (at the time of writing) proposes a solution in Python 3.

Now, someone that was looking for a way to flush output out of python print might come across that question and see the response with hundreds of votes and think that's the way to go. Which is ok.

If someone were to ask the same question, but framed it in the context of Python 3 for example, would it be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: sure, as long as the same answer fits both versions.

Comment: For the specific example, the accepted answer would fit both versions. However, in general, there may be better ways of doing things in newer API's even if the old, possibly deprecated, ways are still acceptable for backwards compatibility.

Comment: So if a question were asked within the context of a particular version, it probably shouldn't be marked as a duplicate unless it is certain that the new version does not offer any new way to do things, otherwise we would just have a lot of questions and answers regarding old versions and a number of answers that may be irrelevant to readers such as a number of Java-related questions where you get "Java 7 only" or "Java 8 only" type of responses because no specific version of Java was specified.

Answer (score 2):

In the process of looking for an answer for the new version, your research unearthed the existing question and answers, right?

Asking the new question is completely appropriate.  When you do, include a link to the existing question, clearly stating "Solutions for version X may be found in the answers to this question; I am asking about version Y".

Even better if you add some detail about why you think the old answers aren't good enough.  Do they no longer work due to broken backward compatibility?  Is there a new language/framework/whatever feature that you think is highly relevant?  If so, craft your question to specify that you prefer a solution that takes advantage of that new feature.